# How to convert Random Forest Model to .tflite?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, random-forest

I am attempting to build a weather forecasting mobile app using Random Forest model. I have created the .py file as below

```
import pandas as pd 
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
    from sklearn import metrics
    import seaborn as sn
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset =pd.read_csv('RFData.csv')
#print(df.head())df.corr()


missing_values = ["NaN", "na", "--"]
df =pd.read_csv("RFData.csv", na_values = missing_values)
print(df['Rain Gauge'].isnull())
median = dataset['Rain Gauge'].mean()
dataset['Rain Gauge'].fillna(median, inplace=True)
print(df['RH'].isnull())
median = dataset['RH'].mean()
dataset['RH'].fillna(median, inplace=True)
print(df['AT'].isnull())
median = dataset['AT'].mean()
dataset['AT'].fillna(median, inplace=True)
print(df['WS Raw'].isnull())
median = dataset['WS Raw'].mean()
dataset['WS Raw'].fillna(median, inplace=True)
print(df['WD Raw'].isnull())
median = dataset['WD Raw'].mean()
dataset['WD Raw'].fillna(median, inplace=True)
print(df['Solar Rad'].isnull())
median = dataset['Solar Rad'].mean()
dataset['Solar Rad'].fillna(median, inplace=True)
print(df['O3 Conc'].isnull())
median = dataset['O3 Conc'].mean()
dataset['O3 Conc'].fillna(median, inplace=True)


X = dataset[['RH', 'AT', 'WS Raw', 'WD Raw', 'Solar Rad', 'O3 Conc']]
print(X.head())
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
#y=dataset.iloc[:,-1]
y = dataset['Rain Gauge']
gender_encoder = LabelEncoder()
y = gender_encoder.fit_transform(y)
y
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X)
X = scaler.transform(X)


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3,random_state=0)
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Can I convert it to .tflite, and if yes, how?.

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/decision-forests/issues/20 Unfortunately it does not support :(

Comment: Yeah! Could you try again with decision forest models from Tensorflow?https://www.tensorflow.org/decision_forests

Comment: @SauravRai Thank you for the support, I'll try with another algorithms.

Comment: @TensorflowSupport Thank You, I'll try with decision forest then..